# Take data from one data frame to another one

Tags: python, dataframe

I have one data frame like that with 15 000 000 rows and 2 columns

```
Index            Stocks              Price
1999-2-21         A                   40
1999-2-22         A                   50
......            ......              ......   
1986-12-22        BN                  3
.....             .....               .....
2017-10-26         BN                  12
......             ......              ........
2017-10-26         ZZZZZ               32
```

And another one where i put the name of my stocks in columns and created an index with date (from 1975 to 2017 be sure to have all my data). size = 15500 rows,3330 colums

```
Index                A       AA            ....            ZZZZZ
1975-01-01
....
2017-10_2017
```

I want to take data from my df1 to put theim in the good place in my df2.

Basically tell python :

```
if this date in df2 = this date in df1
AND if this column name in df2 = this rows in columns 'stocks' in df1
then take the price in df1 to df2
otherwise write nan
```

Comment: I think it'd be simpler to just extract relevant rows by indexing, and then do a Pivot.

Comment: Do you have a link for that function "indexing"?

Comment: `df1 = df1.loc[df2.index]`

Comment: Ok i see now. I tried to do a pivot after "df.pivot(index='Date', columns='ticker', values='close')" but i have an error : "KeyError: 'Date'"

Comment: If your df does not have a Date column, that won't work. If you are trying to pivot on the index, then try calling reset_index() first and then pivot.

Comment: It works! Great thanks

Comment: Congratulations!